# exclude page element from specific pages

Tags: pages, page-template, exclude

I'm using a specific navigation menu that should be present on all but two pages. How can I exclude `<div class="portfolio-nav">` from the specified pages(About & Contact)?

```
<?php get_header();?>

<div class="image-grid">
<div style="width:800px;height:auto;float:right;margin-right:70px;">
<?php if(have_posts()) : ?><?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                  <?php the_content(); ?>
                  <?php endwhile; ?>

        <div class="navigation">
            <div class="prev">
                <?php previous_posts_link(); ?>
            </div><!-- end prev -->
            <div class="next">
                <?php next_posts_link(); ?>
            </div><!-- end next -->
        </div>

        <?php endif; ?>
    </div><!-- end portfolio-nav -->
    <div class="portfolio-nav" style="width:100px;height:auto;float:left;margin-top:50px;">
        <p>COLLECTIONS</p>
        <ul>
                    <li></li>
        </ul>
        </div>

</div><!-- end image-grid -->

<?php get_footer();?>
```

ETA - [live site](http://kimberlygenevieve.com/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if ( ! is_page( array( 'About', 'Contact' ) ) ) : ?>

    <!-- Navigation code -->

<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. To be clear, where am I to put the bit of code you provided?

Comment: Put it around the code you currently have for your navigation. Hence the `<!-- Navigation code -->` comment.

Comment: Got it. If you take a look at the about & contact pages on the site, youll see that the navigation items are still showing despite cleared cache. Any ideas?

Comment: You've uppercase'd your page titles, so need to do the same in your code!

Comment: Even with page titles capitalized, it still doesn't work.

`<div class="navigation">
         <?php if ( ! is_page( array( 'ABOUT', 'CONTACT' ) ) ) : ?>
          <div class="prev">
           <?php previous_posts_link(); ?>
          </div><!-- end prev -->
          <div class="next">
           <?php next_posts_link(); ?>
         <?php endif ?>
         </div><!-- end next -->
        </div>`

Comment: You need to put the `div` inside the condition too.